# startx gives the error "Could not resolve keysym XF86 KeyboardError"

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, xorg, startx

I installed Arch Linux following [this tutorial](https://lampjs.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/easy-installing-arch-linux-dual-boot-with-windows-uefi-or-mbr-for-beginners/). After installing gnome and configuring .xinitrc, running

```
startx
```

gave the error - "Could not resolve keysym XF86 KeyboardError"  and exited. But

```
sudo startx
```

gave some different error and showed three terminals with a clock on top right.

```
systemctl start gdm.service
```

gives the error "Something went wrong" with a "Log Out" button

[Log File](https://pastebin.com/rufk0yzL)

Arch Version - 2018.07.01

While installing

```
xorg-server-utils
```

was not found.

What I have tried  -

```
export XAUTHORITY=/home/subham/.Xauthority
```

This gives the error - "timeout in locking authority" followed by a black screen and then the error "No protocol specifies..xinit: giving upxinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporary unavailable"

Setting XAUTHORITY back to ""  doesn't change the error.

Comment: Running `sudo startx` will probably have resulted in your `~/.Xauthority` file being owned by `root` and unwritable by you - don't do that (aside from the security implications of running an X server as root)

Comment: -1: Sorry, but OP makes no sense, starting with its title... I would advise to just stay away from anything that uses words such as "easy", "archlinux", "beginner" in one sentence, and all the more so when that sentence is some fly-by-night tutorial title ... Use **Archlinux wikis**; they are the best thing available all around.